# What table a record came from and if more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 4 tables (`Table1` through `Table4`) and column `CODE` in each table. I use a `UNION ALL` to identify where they come from

```
select  distinct CODE, 'Table1'  from Table1 where TABLE1_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
union all
select  distinct CODE, 'Table2' from Table2 where TABLE2_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
union all
select  distinct CODE, 'Table3' from Table3 where TABLE3_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
union all
select  distinct CODE, 'Table4' from Table4 where TABLE4_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
```

Sometimes the same `CODE` can be in more than one table, and I want to identify and return the result in a below table form. When code in more than one table I want to flag it as `Y` in the `Multisource` column.

```
CODE    Table1  Table2  Table3  Table4  Multisource

12345   Y       N       N       N       N
34233   Y       Y       N       N       Y
45345   Y       N       N       N       N
23417   Y       N       Y       N       Y
45346   Y       N       N       N       Y
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `conditional aggregation` to pivot your results:

```
select code, 
       max(case when tbl = 'Table1' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'Table1',
       max(case when tbl = 'Table2' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'Table2',
       max(case when tbl = 'Table3' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'Table3',
       max(case when tbl = 'Table4' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'Table4',
       case when count(*) > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Multisource'
from (
  select  distinct CODE, 'Table1' as tbl from Table1 where TABLE1_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
  union all
  select  distinct CODE, 'Table2' from Table2 where TABLE2_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
  union all
  select  distinct CODE, 'Table3' from Table3 where TABLE3_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
  union all
  select  distinct CODE, 'Table4' from Table4 where TABLE4_EFF_STARt >= '01/01/2014'
) t
group by code
```